# How to put background color on mui useStyle?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I dont know what i am missing on this, or whats wrong on this code, but the background color is not reflecting, please help, thanks

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: '-webkit-fill-available',
    margin: 0,
    paddingLeft: 30,
    background: 'rgba(239, 243, 246, 1)' //it doesnt work why?
  },
}));

const Homepage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root} id="style">
      <h4>About this School</h4>
      <About />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you try `backgroundColor` property instead of `background`?

Comment: yes but still not workin

Comment: If other styles which you have defined are being this div, then check the styles under browser's inspect element, see if there is any other style that is overriding this `background` property.

Comment: I tried the above code, there is nothing wrong in the code. IMO It must be some other background style that is overriding this style.

Answer (score 1):

Add comma at the end of background code.

```
  root: {
    height: '-webkit-fill-available',
    margin: 0,
    paddingLeft: 30,
    background: 'rgba(239, 243, 246, 1)',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Prathamesh Koshti said it's working well in the latest version. just inspect the element and check whether the background color was overriding or not.
[working code here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/styledcomponents-material-demo-forked-7uodr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)